# How to copy all files listed in notepad.txt to a different location

Tags: windows-7, windows, script

I have a `notepad.txt` document (file) that contains the file-pathname of several files on my PC.  For example:

```
C:\Users\Foo\Pictures\Photographs\September\P1030944.jpg
C:\Users\Foo\Videos\Art\Movies\Class\movie.avi
C:\Users\Foo\Music\Jazz\20051.mp3
```

...etc.

The files listed in the text document are found in different locations on my PC. Is there a way to move these files from their sources into one destination (for example, `H:\Users\Destination`) using their pathname in the `notepad.txt` document only?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command

```
for /f "tokens=*" %A in (notepad.txt) do @move "%~A" "H:\Users\Destination\%~nxA"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in PowerShell:

> Get-Content .\notepad.txt | ForEach-Object {Move-Item -Force "$_" "H:\Users\Destination\"}

- `Get-Content .\notepad.txt` grabs each line in the file`notepad.txt`.
- `ForEach-Object` cycles through each line piped in from `Get-Content`
- `Move-Item -Force` moves the file to the new location, regardless if it is already there.  Without the switch `-Force`, if the same filename existed in the destination directory, the script would throw an error.
- `$_` is the value of the line piped in from `Get-Content` (such as `C:\Users\Foo\Pictures\Photographs\September\P1030944.jpg`).  The double quotes around `$_`  arent mandatory, but are necessary if the path or filename have a space in it.